# Efficiency of collection.stream().skip().findFirst()

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Suppose `set` is a `HashSet` with `n` elements and `k` is some `int` between `0` (inclusive) and `n` (exclusive).

Can somebody explain, in simple terms, what actually happens when you do this?

```
set.stream().skip(k).findFirst();
```

In particular, what is the time complexity of this? Does the addition of `spliterator()` to the `Collection` interface mean that we now have faster access to "random" elements of collections than would have been possible with Java 7?

Comment: Not generally speaking, no, and not with `HashSet`.  `HashSet.spliterator()` doesn't have the `ORDERED` property, so you may get undefined behavior here.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks, I thought not, but just wanted confirmation.

Comment: You might notice that the `Spliterator` interface itself has no `skip` method or any other way of moving the pointer to the current element. So there is no way of implementing a “faster access to ‘random’ elements of collections” atop this.

Comment: @Holger Yes it was a pretty stupid question. I need to look into this properly as I'm still not entirely sure what a spliterator is.

Comment: I don’t think that this is a stupid question. By looking at the Stream API itself, it’s more than often unclear where an actual potential for internal optimizations lies and where not. Some parts are intentionally left unspecified and some obvious-looking potential is astonishingly ignored in the current implementation. There seems to be an air of mystery around it to a lot of developers…

Comment: @LouisWasserman I just raised an eyebrow at "undefined behavior". Ask some C++ guy what this means ;-) The behavior is defined clearly: The stream will return all elements of the set (in unspecified order).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current implementation has O(k) complexity and moreless equivalent to the following:

```
Iterator<?> it = set.iterator();
for(int i=0; i<k && it.hasNext(); i++) it.next();
return it.hasNext() ? Optional.of(it.next()) : Optional.empty();
```

Current implementation never takes into account `ORDERED` characteristic for sequential streams. The piece of code cited in @the8472 answer works for parallel streams only. In parallel case the amortized complexity is roughly O(k/n) where n is the number of processors.

Answer (score 3):

As louis mentions skip does not really make sense on unordered streams, in fact it's currently (jdk 1.8) implemented in a way where the following method optimizes the skip away under some circumstances:

```
        Spliterator<T> unorderedSkipLimitSpliterator(Spliterator<T> s,
                                                     long skip, long limit, long sizeIfKnown) {
            if (skip <= sizeIfKnown) {
                // Use just the limit if the number of elements
                // to skip is <= the known pipeline size
                limit = limit >= 0 ? Math.min(limit, sizeIfKnown - skip) : sizeIfKnown - skip;
                skip = 0;
            }
            return new StreamSpliterators.UnorderedSliceSpliterator.OfRef<>(s, skip, limit);
        }
```

This is valid because it is equivalent to simply traversing the source collection in a different order.